# OpenCL: AMD Fusion and CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Tags: opencl

I got some problems with clCreateBuffer in OpenCL. I am working with an AMD Fusion processor (A10-5800k), so both devices (CPU and GPU) should be able to work on each others memory.

For the read and result buffer I do:

```
bufRead = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, size, data, &err);
bufWrite = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, size, result, &err);
```

When I call my kernel, the "result" array doesn't change. I know that normal GPUs would copy the data to the device memory and work on that. Would normal GPUs copy the data back afterwards?

However, I did hope that the Fusion GPU does not copy the data, because it can work on the same pointer. Unfortunately, I don't see any change in the "result" array. When I read "bufWrite" with clEnqueueReadBuffer I see the changes. (I do clFinish before reading "result", so the data should be written)

Does anyone know how to truly work on the same array with CPU and GPU? I really want to avoid clEnqueueReadBuffer.

Thanks,

Tomas

Comment: I don't have time to answer your question right now, but here is an answer I wrote regarding APUs from a while ago, which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766578/access-path-in-zero-copy-in-opencl/12786498#12786498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I searched quite a while for an answer. It is possible but only under certain circumstances.

You need a GPU that has VM (virtual memory) enabled. You can check this with clinfo. Look for the "VM" in Driver version, e.g.,

```
             Driver version: CAL 1.4.1695 (VM)
```

I have a quite new APU under Linux and VM is not supported. I think it is not supported for all GPUs under Linux. I will try Windows next. It is plausible because it needs to interact with the OS on this. I hope Linux support will come in the future.

Anyway, to use it, you need to:

1. Create your buffers with  CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR.
2. Access the buffer from the Host with clEnqueueMapBuffer and release it after reading/writing with clEnqueueUnmapMemObject.
3. When VM is enabled, nothing is copied and you have direct access / without VM it is working as well but it will copy the data.

check out the AMD APP OpenCL Programming Guide Section 4.5.2 - Placement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you. In OpenCL (for any target platform type, CPU or GPU), a call to clCreateBuffer will allocate some memory on the device and will copy data from host pointer to newly allocated memory (althought this copy may done only when a kernel is invoked with this pointer as argument). I do not think it it possible for a host and a device to work on the same memory without "synchronization" (aka clEnqueueReadBuffer).

Comment: For example, when you use the CPU with OpenCL (device == host == CPU) and you create a buffer with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, the memory is not copied and you work on the actual data. With AMD Fusion, this should be possible for the GPU as well (at least I think it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms/devices, a call to **clFinish** is enough to synchronize host memory from device memory. A call to **clEnqueueReadBuffer**, or **clEnqueueMapBuffer** is required in the general case.  The pointer returned by **clEnqueueMapBuffer** should be related to the host ptr you provided when creating the buffer.